# Find Users e-mail based on the current IPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am using Windows Authentication in an ASP.net MVC application. I would like to query Active Directory to get a users e-mail address based on the current user:

```
IPrincipal principal = HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Is there a way I can use Active Directory to query for their e-mail address?

Comment: This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jpinquie/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-get-domain-user-information-from-active-directory-in-c.aspx) may help you out.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)) {
  using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName)) {
    if (user != null) {
       return user.EmailAddress;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please improve the quality of the answer explaining it. Thank you